# Filter an array based on user input in text box realtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hey looking to live filter an array of JSON objects rendered during component creation in vue js

on the mounted life cycle hook  have this:

```
const search = document.querySelector('.search input');
    search.addEventListener('keyup',()=>{
      const term = search.value.trim();
         
         this.books = this.books.Title.filter(function (item) {
            return item.Title.match(term)   
})
      })
```

I have tried a few different methods and not able to find a function on the array that allows me to filter dynamically and update my array

any thing to point me in the right direction would be helpful!

search box:

```
  <form class="search">
      <input class="form-control m-auto" type="text" name="search" placeholder="search" />
   </form>
```

full code

```
template>
  <div>
    <div class="shelf" style="margin: 40px;">
      <h6>Here you can search a title of any book that is in the list</h6>
      <label for="fname">Search term:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" v-model="searchText">
      <ul class="collapsible popout">
        <h6 v-if="searchResults.length">Search results</h6>
        <li class="li" v-for="(book,index) in searchResults" :key="index">
          <div class="collapsible-header">
            <h5>
              {{ book.Title }}
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
            <p>Author: {{book.Author}}</p>
            <p>Category: {{book.Category}}</p>
            <div class="loan" v-if="book.Loan">on loan</div>
            <div class="owned" v-if="book.Owned">Owned</div>
            <!-- vue-router required to run this -->
            <!-- <router-link :to="{name:'EditBook', params:{id:book.id}}">
            <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
            </router-link>-->
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h5>Here is the list of avalaible books</h5>
    <ul class="collapsible popout" style="margin: 40px;">
      <li class="li" v-for="(book,index) in books" :key="index">
        <div class="collapsible-header">
          <h5>
            <book-icon/>
            {{ book.Title }}
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          <p>Author: {{book.Author}}</p>
          <p>Category: {{book.Category}}</p>
          <div class="loan" v-if="book.Loan">on loan</div>
          <div class="owned" v-if="book.Owned">Owned</div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import M from 'materialize-css'
export default {
  name: 'Shelf',
  data () {
    return {
      books:[],
      searchText: ''
    }
  },
  mounted(){
       var DropDownElems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
        let options = {
          inDuration: 300,
          outDuration: 300,
          hover: true, // Activate on hover
          coverTrigger: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
          };
        M.Dropdown.init(DropDownElems,options);
        var ColapseElems = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
       M.Collapsible.init(ColapseElems)

    },
  created(){
      db.collection('Bookshelf').get()
      .then(snapshot=>{
        snapshot.forEach(book => {
          let b = book.data()
          b.id = book.id
          this.books.push(b)
             });
      })
    },
 computed: {
     searchResults() {
     if (this.searchText.length === 0) return "";
         return this.books.filter(book => book.Title.match(this.searchText));    
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style >
.loan{
    background: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 4px 3px 8px 1px #969696;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 3px 8px 1px #969696;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
.li{
  margin-left: 70px auto;
  margin-right: 70px auto;
 
}
.edit{
  left: 80%;
}
</style>
```

I am able to verify the output of the books array just fine all looks good

Sample of array:
0:
Author: "string"
Category: "string"
Loan: boolean
Owned: boolean
ReadingNow: boolean
Title: "string"
id: "string"

from console:
[image]

when I run return this.books.filter(book => console.log(book.Title)); for debugging I get a string
[image]

Comment: What is the data model? `this.books.Title.filter` looks wrong

Comment: can you share the full code please

Comment: edited - main post thanks @KarlL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to vue, let me give you an example how to do it by using Vue:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Our searchText property, used to filter the books
    searchText: '',
    // An array of books by Gabo
    books: [{
      title: "El coronel no tiene quien le escriba"
    },
    {
      title: "100 años de soledad"
    },
    {
      title: "Memorias de mis putas tristes"
    },
    {
      title: "El amor en los tiempos del cólera"
    }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    // A computed property, magically listening changes
    // in the searchText property
    searchResults() {
      // If searchText property is empty, then return a empty string
      if (this.searchText.length === 0) return '';
      // return only books with titles that match with
      // the searchText string
      return this.books.filter(book => book.title.match(this.searchText))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <label for="fname">Search term:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" v-model="searchText">
  {{ searchResults }} 
</div>
```

If you have doubts about it or need further explanation, please let me know it

For more details, check this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-joliot-mty2y)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218490/discussion-on-answer-by-andres-foronda-filter-an-array-based-on-user-input-in-te).

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close, but a few improvements are needed.

First of all, you don't need to add "standard" keyup event listener. With vue you can use `v-model`:

in Vue app:

```
//...
name: 'Shelf',
  data () {
    return {
      books:[],
      term: ''
    }
  },
//...
```

```html
<input type="text" v-model="term">
```

I suggest you use computed properties to get filtered book without effort:

```js
computed: {
  filteredBooks() {
    const filteredBooks = this.books.filter(book => {  
        const regex = new RegExp(this.term.trim());
        return String(book.Title).match(regex)   
    });
  
    return filteredBooks;
  }
}
```

Now you can iterate through foundedBooks to get filtered books:

```html
<input type="text" v-model="term">

<div v-for="(book, index) in filteredBooks" :key="index">
  {{ index+1 }}. {{ book.Title }}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I keep getting
"Property or method "foundedBooks" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Comment: Sorry, I made typo, it should be `filteredBooks`.

Comment: sorry still doing it after the typo - I caught that earlier too same result